# How to write a SQL query to join two different date columns with the date dimension table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a "supply" table with columns as sku, snapshot_date, target_week, quantity etc. And there is "date_dimension" master table with fields as date, week, month, quarter, year, quarter_date.

Now, my task is to join the supply with the date_dimension table on date = snapshot_date to get the details from date_dimension table for each snapshot_date.

Also, I have to do the same for getting the details for each target_week which can be done by joining on date = target_week.

That means, I am doing join two times and the supply table has millions of rows of data so two joins would be expensive I believe.

Is there a better way to solve this and show output as follows:

```
snapshot_date | week_snapshot_date | month_snapshot_date | year_snapshot_date | ....| target_week | week_target_week| month_target_week | year_target_week |.....
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select s.*, . . .   -- the columns from the dimension table
from supply s left join
     date_dimension ds
     on ds.date = s.snapshot_date left join
     date_dimension dt
     on dt.date = s.target_week;
```

Note:  This uses `left join`s in case either of the columns have `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you Gordon :) But, where should I should use the "( and )" brackets while doing left join as its three tables continuously written right

Comment: @JaahnaviTiruthani . . . No parentheses are needed.  They are only needed in MS Access and your question is tagged "mysql".

Comment: Actually I am using Bigquery SQL to do the query

Comment: @JaahnaviTiruthani . . . This is fine in BigQuery.  I fixed the database tag.